# SQL conditional inserts, and other multiple queries done in a atomic/all or nothing/non interleaved way

Tags: sql, database, concurrency, locking, atomic

Let's say i have an application relying on a SQL 'users' table and want to avoid multiple users with the same name:

When I insert a new user in my table, I must make sure that there is no similar rows already. So that is 2 queries, the second one only happening if the first one returned nothing:

```
-query1: select * from users where username='Marie-Antoinette'
-query2: insert into users ('','Marie-Antoinette','37')
```

Multiple applications instances access the shared database simultaneously, how do I make sure that no query is inserted between query1 and query2? That it is done as an atomic operation in the DB with nothing in between?

---

There may be a way, a syntax to do conditional inserts but my question is more about "**how to make sure i can make N queries with the guarantee that no queries from other clients will be interleaved in my batch**"?

Let's say I have, in my application, an operation that requires 4 queries:

my operation  consists of:

```
-query1: insert stuff in table 1
-query2: select stuff from table 2
-query3: insert stuff in table 3
-query4: update stuff in table 4
```

Those should be considered as an atomic operation, it's all or nothing, but not only that, during that sequence, there must be the guarantee that there won't be anything interleaved (since between those queries the database has no integrity, and that those 4 tables must be frozen while this operation happens) and that multiple clients can trigger that operation and that the multiple calls will be somehow queued rather than failing.

over time, that would be:

```
-client #1 query 1
-client #1 query 2
-client #1 query 3
-client #1 query 4

-client #2 query 1
-client #2 query 2
-client #2 query 3
-client #2 query 4

-client #1 query 1
-client #1 query 2
-client #1 query 3
-client #1 query 4
```

What is the recommended approach to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

The recommended approach is to add a unique index (or equivalently a unique constraint) on the table so having duplicate user names fails on the insert:

```
create unique index users_username on users(username);
```

Comment: Can be tricky to handle the right exception without handling others. I prefer not producing errors at all by getting the check right.

Answer (score 1):

After further research, it seems I have to use "transactions" that must have all the "ACID" Properties (for the second part of my question, the general case).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID

However, using transactions alone doesn't give me all the guarantees that I mentioned in my questions. The "Isolation" guarantee, in particular, can be problematic.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)

SQL database have a "Transaction Isolation Level" property that can be checked and must be set to "Serializable"

for example, in my MySQL database:

```
SELECT @@global.tx_isolation; 

>> REPEATABLE-READ

SET GLOBAL TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE

>> OK

SELECT @@global.tx_isolation; 

>> SERIALIZABLE
```